# div contents are not moving with parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an expandable and contractable side menu that works beautifully. I have a few child divs contained within 'left_menu'. This 'left_menu' is coded within CSS to begin off the page. My javascript will then call for the full 'left_menu' div to expand to size This works, and also any child divs move with it. However, when I add text or a ul inside of 'left_menu_bottom_content', this content does not begin off of the page as it should. When the side-menu is expanded, you can tell it is in the right place. This is why I believe maybe it's a JS issue.

I have played around with the positioning and don't believe that to be the issue, but it may be.

```
<div id='left_menu' class='lmenu'>
    <div id='left_menu_top_options'>
    </div>
    <div id='left_menu_bottom'>
        <div id='left_menu_bottom_right_border'></div>
        <div id='left_menu_bottom_content'>
            test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>





#left_menu_bottom_right_border{
    height:100%;
    width:3px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    background-color:#464646;
}

#left_menu_bottom_content{
    width: calc(100% - 3px);
    height:100%;
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
}

#left_menu{
    position:fixed;
    width: 0px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#00a2ff;

    transition: all .25s linear;
    z-index:9999;
}

#left_menu_top_options{
    width:100%;
    height:25px;
    background-color:#464646;
}

#left_menu_bottom{
    height: calc(100% - 25px);
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#00a2ff;
}






function changeMenu() { 
    var $menu_content_width = document.getElementById("menu_content").style.width;

    if($menu_content_width == "80%"){   
        document.getElementById("arrow_move").innerHTML = "&#8250;";
        document.getElementById("menu_content").style.width = "90%";
        document.getElementById("menu_content").style.marginLeft= "5%"; 
        document.getElementById("button_wrapper").style.marginLeft= "0";
        document.getElementById("left_menu").style.width = "0";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("arrow_move").innerHTML = "&#8249;";    
        document.getElementById("menu_content").style.width = "80%";
        document.getElementById("menu_content").style.marginLeft= "15%";    
        document.getElementById("button_wrapper").style.marginLeft= "12%";  
        document.getElementById("left_menu").style.width = "12%";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "12%";    
    }

}
</script>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to rectify the situation by instead of using width, using marginLeft on the 'left_menu' div. Here is my code.

Instead, the div now begins off the page, and is brought in and out. Rather than being expanded and contracted via width.

```
function changeMenu() { 
    var $menu_content_width = document.getElementById("menu_content").style.width;

    if($menu_content_width == "80%"){   
        document.getElementById("arrow_move").innerHTML = "&#8250;";
        document.getElementById("menu_content").style.width = "90%";
        document.getElementById("menu_content").style.marginLeft= "5%"; 
        document.getElementById("button_wrapper").style.marginLeft= "0";
        document.getElementById("left_menu").style.marginLeft = "-12%";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("arrow_move").innerHTML = "&#8249;";    
        document.getElementById("menu_content").style.width = "80%";
        document.getElementById("menu_content").style.marginLeft= "15%";    
        document.getElementById("button_wrapper").style.marginLeft= "12%";  
        document.getElementById("left_menu").style.marginLeft = "0";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "12%";    
    }
}



#left_menu{
    position:fixed;
    width: 12%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#00a2ff;
    margin-left:-12%;
    transition: all .25s linear;
    z-index:9999;
}
```